# flash message and redirect in cakephp3

Tags: redirect, flash, cakephp, cakephp3

I have the below code in one of my controller files.`$this->Flash->error("error message!");
return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'home']);`.My problem is, flash message is not displaying on the redirected page. Can anyone help?

Comment: Flash messages are stored in the session, make sure it's working (ie that you're receiving the session cookie, the cookie is sent after the redirect, the session is picked up, etc...)

Comment: Having cakephp 2 and it is not working too.

Answer (score 1):

**in controller:**

```
$this->Flash->error("error message!");
return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'home']);
```

**in your  home.ctp or layouts/default.ctp**

```
<?= $this->Flash->render() ?>
```

** in your Element/Flash**

create **error.ctp** if . not exists

Comment: Thanks, but still the flash message is not displaying.

Comment: set cakephp debug to true, clear browser cache,  open developer tools and double check does flash message exist in your html code (maybe hidden by css)

Comment: flash message does not exist in html.

Comment: Can you produce with success, default, set methods?

Comment: None of them are working. when I commented out the ```return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'home']);``` line in controller, flash message displays on that page, but does not display after redirect.

Comment: add to home.ctp  <?= $this->Flash->render() ?>